# Not your typical crossword

Tags: crosswords

[image]

> **Across**
>   5. a joke of grand scale
>   6. drugged sea
>   7. very friendly walker
>   8. slithering gift
>   10. give parts of songs
>   **Down**
>   1. sneaky carrier
>   2. most difficult dislike
>   3. violent injury of highest form
>   4. thin expensive ore pieces
>   9. hot surface for people's opinions

Comment: Just noticed I missed one box on 2 down. it should be one longer. my apologies. ill edit in a correct grid

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All the clues are

> in two parts, one defining the answer and the other defining an anagram of the answer.

So the solution is, with help from [gnovice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62819/39764) and [Aces](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62828/39764):

> - in the order in which they appear in the clue
>  - asterisked answer is the one that goes in the grid
>  - if no asterisk, then either answer can go in the grid

Across

> 5. COMICS* / COSMIC (thanks to [gnovice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62819/39764))
>  6. COCAINE / OCEANIC*
>  7. CHARMER / MARCHER* (thanks to [Aces](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62828/39764))
>  8. SERPENT / PRESENT*
>  10. SERVE / VERSE

Down

> 1. COVERT / VECTOR* (thanks to [gnovice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62819/39764))
>  2. HARDEST / HATREDS (thanks to [gnovice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62819/39764))
>  3. MUTILATE / ULTIMATE (thanks to [gnovice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62819/39764))
>  4. SLIVERS* / SILVERS
>  9. STOVE* / VOTES

Commentary:

> Not a bad puzzle, but it would be improved if
>  a) there was a unique solution; and
>  b) the clues agreed in tense, case and number with the answers. "parts of songs" is VERSES, not VERSE; COCAINE is a drug, not drugged, and so on.

Comment: see my edit. sorry for the trouble

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll keep those in mind. Hope it was enjoyable at least. Was a little surprised you caught the trick so quickly. Nicely done.

Answer (score 9):

Some answers based on [Rupert's pattern](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/62817/43477) (answer in parentheses):

Across

> 5. COSMIC (COMICS)

Down

> 1. COVERT (VECTOR)
>  2. HARDEST HATREDS (either works)
>  3. MUTILATE ULTIMATE (either works)

Comment: see my edit for 2 down.

Comment: @Dragonrage: Gotcha. Updated my answer for that.

Answer (score 5):

It might be a stretch, but for 7 Across using Rupert's pattern:

> CHARMER/MARCHER*

Comment: I'm going to put it in and call the puzzle done.

Comment: Your answers are also anagrams of each other! $(+1)$ :P

Answer (score 3):

4 Down (thin expensive ore pieces) might be

> Bangles
>  Bangles are thin bracelets made from precious metals (smelted from ore)

Comment: The only definition I am finding for 4 down is a bracelet of some sort - how are you connecting it to ore?

Comment: @Jordan.J.D See edit.

Comment: Thanks for the upvotes... but it looks like I was waaay off :)